# Problema com validação de CPF

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
@model Projeto1.Models.Cliente

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Criar Novo Cliente</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10" id="CPF" name="CPF">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="TELEFONE">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="CELULAR">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celular, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celular, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sexo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sexo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sexo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstadoCivil, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataCadastro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataCadastro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataCadastro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataAlteracao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataAlteracao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataAlteracao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataExcluido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataExcluido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataExcluido, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Criar Novo Cliente" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Ver lista de clientes", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~bundles/inputmask")
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: No código que compartilhou aqui só tem uma máscara no campo do CPF, se tem alguma validação no backend você não compartilhou. Você precisa melhorar muito sua pergunta.

Comment: Qual é o problema? apresente um [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!

Pelo que ví no seu código, você está utilizando somente uma biblioteca de máscara de CPF.

Não existe nenhuma validação de CPF válido.

Você pode fazer isso no seu backend.

Abraços